# MSE WebM finishing before duration with no end event

Tags: javascript, html5-video, webm, media-source

I've got a strange issue with a WebM in Media Source Extensions.

The video duration (according to videoEl.duration) is 8.354999999999999.

The video gets to current time = 8.328015 and stops, with no event being fired.

The MediaSource duration is 8.403, and there is no event fired when that finishes that I can see.

I can't find anything wrong with the video file. My code is fairly standard append to buffer and it works with other WebMs.

Here is my code (in Redux Saga)

```
while(chunks.length && !complete){
        const event = yield take(sourceBufferEvents)
        console.log(event)
        if(event.type === "updateend"){
            if(loading){
                yield fork(loaded, true)

                while(loading){
                    const event = yield take(videoEvents)

                    if(chunks && event.type === "playing"){
                        loading = false
                        yield fetchNextSegment(asset.id, asset.remoteUrl, sourceBuffer,  chunks.shift())
                        videoEvents.close()
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                yield fetchNextSegment(asset.id, asset.remoteUrl, sourceBuffer, chunks.shift() ) 
                index ++;
            }    
        }
       
        if(total === index){
            // yield mediaSource.endOfStream()
            // complete = true
            while(sourceBuffer.updating){
                console.log(total, index)
            }
            console.log(sourceBuffer.updating)
           
        }
    }
```

These events are called on updateEnd.

sourceBuffer.updating is never false

I get `DOMException: Failed to execute 'endOfStream' on 'MediaSource': The 'updating' attribute is true on one or more of this MediaSource's SourceBuffers.`

When I try and end the stream

Comment: show your code, do you call endOfStream()?

Comment: @beek _"My code works with other WebMs... I can't find anything wrong with the video file."_ If other files work then I would still suspect something is wrong with that specific webM. What happens if you re-encode the file? Are various media players all giving a consistent same duration (_eg:_ browser time vs VLC time vs FFplay time)?

Comment: @Kaiido no I don't. Will look at that thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per Kaiido's comment, I had to use endOfStream and I was missing the final updateended event.

Comment: Interesting, so how did it "work fine with other webM" if you never used endOfStream? Were they short duration files (seconds) or such? Just wondering if this quirk could be useful in some situation...

Comment: Possibly the estimated duration was close enough to the actual duration? Not sure.